# Static method, Zend_View error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a static method 'findAll' on a model which basically gets all rows with certain criteria. This method works fine and I can call it using:

```
$m::findAll();
```

Where $m is the model name as a variable. I can output this and it returns correct results. However, when assigning this to a variable in the Zend_View object, as:

```
$this->view->viewvariable = $m::findAll();
```

I get the error:

> Zend_Db_Table_Exception: Too many
>   columns for the primary key

Any ideas why?

Find all function:

```
final public static function findAll($where = false, array $options = array()) {
  $object = new static();

  if (!empty($options)) $options = array_merge($object->options, $options);
  else $options = $object->options;

  $run = $object->buildDefaultSelect($where, $options);
  $rows = $run->fetchAll();
  if ($options['asObject'] == true) {
   $result = array();
   foreach ($rows as $r) {
    $class = new static();
    $class->setInfo($r);
    $result[] = $class;
   }
   return $result;
  } else {
   if (count($rows) > 0) return $rows;
   else return array();
  }
 }
```

*Note:* **This function works fine** everywhere apart from when assigning to a view variable. If I run the below (not assigning it to a view variable), it shows the correct array data.

```
   var_dump($m::findAll($module['where'], $module['options']));
   exit;
```

In my view (I have replaced the actual name with viewvariable for the sake of this post):

```
<?php foreach($this->viewvariable as $item) { ?>
//Do some echoing of data in $item
//Close foreach
```

Comment: Does this model have a composite PK? And do you get this error on assignment or when you try to iterate the RS in the template?

Comment: Would help to see a little of the code behind `findAll()`

Comment: could you paste code behind $object->buildDefaultSelect($where, $options)?

Comment: You say `var_dump($m::findAll($module['where'], $module['options']));` works, does `var_dump($m::findAll());` work? Because that's what you're passing to `Zend_View`.

Comment: It's a bit big to post here but essentially it runs through the $options variable looking for a limit/group/order items and then builds a Db_Table select() based on this data.

Comment: Can you post a sample of how you used the view variable in the view script?

Comment: Updated: Please see the end of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the issue is with `Zend_View`. It's hard to tell without seeing your code, but my guess is that `findAll()` is using the `Zend_Table_Db` `find()` function incorrectly.

To my knowledge, **the only place that throws that exception** is the `find()` function on `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`.

Perhaps, inside the `findAll()` function (or in a function it calls) you're doing one of these:

```
$zendDbTable->find(1,2) //is looking for a compound key
$zendDbTable->find(array(1,2)) //is looking for two rows
```

When you really want the opposite.

Comment: I don't use the find function anywhere in my code.... see updated post for function

Comment: But something is calling it, possibly, `$run->fetchAll()`. `Zend_View` won't be throwing a `Zend_Db_Table_Exception`. My guess is you can't run `$m::findAll()` without any arguments (your sample working code adds arguments).

Comment: Thanks for the update but it produces a parse error. Running findAll without vars is ok.

Comment: I have found the problem, kinda, it's due to several functions automatically being called from my created objects. I commented out the find function in the abstract and tracked it down. As you're answer pointed me to this file, you have the answer :) Thanks for the help

Comment: @Ashley - Yup, knew it wasn't something in `Zend_View` - aren't detailed exceptions informative? :-)

Comment: The problem was that the exception was killing the actual error that was causing the problem (it was only a notice.. not sure why). Not so handy exception handling from Zend... :(